# Change label style of amCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

See the image in amCharts. I just want to display on month short names like Jan, Feb, Mar, etc. Instead of displaying the first month of the year like Jan it displays 2016... see highlighted section:

[image]

```
    AmCharts.makeChart("MonthlySaleChart",
            {
                "type": "serial",
                "categoryField": "date",
                "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM",
                "theme": "default",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "minPeriod": "MM",
                    "parseDates": true
                },
                "chartCursor": {
                    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "MMM YYYY"
                },
                "chartScrollbar": {},
                "trendLines": [],
                "graphs": [
                    {
                        "bullet": "round",
                        "id": "AmGraph-1",
                        "title": "This Year",
                        "valueField": "ThisMonth"
                    },
                    {
                        "bullet": "square",
                        "id": "AmGraph-2",
                        "title": "Last Year",
                        "valueField": "LastMonth"
                    }
                ],
                "guides": [],
                "valueAxes": [
                    {
                        "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                        "title": "Sales in Thousands (000)"
                    }
                ],
                "allLabels": [],
                "balloon": {},
                "legend": {
                    "useGraphSettings": true
                },
                "titles": [
                    {
                        "color": "#20C5AE",
                        "id": "Title-1",
                        "size": 15,
                        "text": "SALES By Month"
                    }
                ],
                "dataProvider": data
            }
        );
```

Comment: Please provide more information on what you have done so far. What have you tried, what were the results?

Comment: I just provide three values to char one is date & other two are some int. i just want the month short names in a series but in displays 2016 instead of 'jan'.

Comment: my chart displays the first month on jan like 2016 or 2015 . i just want it to display simple jan like feb or mar

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: i posted code see if you can help

Answer (score 0):

To disable showing a year instead of Jan, set [`markPeriodChange`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#markPeriodChange) to `false` in `categoryAxis`:

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "minPeriod": "MM",
  "parseDates": true,
  "markPeriodChange": false
}
```